# How to run a spider on multiple URLs while concatenating a string to the URLs

Tags: python, scrapy

I want a spider to run on multiple URLs. However I wish to take input from the user, concatenate it to my original URL and then let the spider crawl them. Here is what I am doing for one of those URLs

```
class ProductsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "gaming"

    def start_requests(self):
        product = input("Enter the item you are looking for")
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=f'https://www.czone.com.pk/search.aspx?kw={product}',
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
```

The above code runs perfectly fine for one URL. One way to have multiple URLs is to have a list as start_url but in case of even URL the spider returns an error that says
"[scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h"
Please help!

Comment: Please post the list of urls, seems that some urls have not a valid schema.

Comment: so the second url is  "https://pcfanatics.pk/search?type=product&q=" and the third is "http://www.gtstore.pk/searchresults.php?inputString=".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code:

```
import scrapy


class ProductsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "gaming"

    def __init__(self, product='', **kwargs):
        self.start_urls = [
            f'https://www.czone.com.pk/search.aspx?kw={product}',
            f'https://pcfanatics.pk/search?type=product&q={product}',
            f'https://gtstore.pk/searchresults.php?inputString={product}',
        ]
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def start_requests(self):
        for s_url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=s_url,
                callback=self.parse,
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        print(self.name)
        ... do parse things ...
```

The right way to get input in scrapy spiders is to use `-a` option when run it, for example to run this spider you should use:

```
scrapy crawl gaming -a product='foo'
```

or

```
scrapy runspider <spider_filename> -a product='foo'
```

The error that you have with urls could be due a bad formatting, using

```
            f'https://www.czone.com.pk/search.aspx?kw={product}',
            f'https://pcfanatics.pk/search?type=product&q={product}',
            f'https://gtstore.pk/searchresults.php?inputString={product}',
```

didn't get me any issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, the solution is as follows:

My CODE:

```
import scrapy

class ProductsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = "games"
    
    product = input("laptop")
    product2 = input("desktop")
    product3 = input("cameras")
    
    def start_requests(self):
        
        urls =[f'https://www.czone.com.pk/search.aspx?kw={self.product}', f'https://www.czone.com.pk/search.aspx?kw={self.product2}', f'https://www.czone.com.pk/search.aspx?kw={self.product3}']
        
        for url in urls:
            
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url =url,
                callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

The same thing as alternative:

CODE:

```
import scrapy
class ProductsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "games2"
    product = input(["laptop","desktop","cameras"])
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=f'https://www.czone.com.pk/search.aspx?kw={self.product}',
            callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

OUTPUT:

```
laptop
desktop
cameras
['laptop', 'desktop', 'cameras']

2021-08-12 16:53:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.czone.com.pk/search.aspx?kw=> (referer: None)
2021-08-12 16:53:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-08-12 16:53:39 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 312,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 19982,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200
```

Comment: Thus way, you can input yours desired urls.